# Module not found error using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My node application does not run when i run `node index.js`
Here are the files I have:

File index.js:

```
const command = require('discord.js-commando')
const bot = new commando.Client();

bot.registery.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.register.registerDefaults();
bot.registery.regusterCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands")

bot.login('zzzzz');
```

And the file random.js:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando')

class DiceRollCommand extends commando.Command {
   constructor(client) {
       super(client, {
            name: 'roll',
            group: 'random',
            memberName: 'roll',
            description: 'Rolls a die'
        });
    }

    async run(message, args) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        message.reply("You rolled a die") + roll);
    }
}

module.exports = DiceRollCommand;
```

This is the stacktrace of the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dange\Desktop\bots\js\commands\random'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: In future please do not post code in external links. post it in your post instead.  If the link breaks future visitors may not benefit from this question.

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is possibly a combination of typos and directory structure.  Try making the following changes:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando')
const bot = new commando.Client();

// Typo in the following: should be, bot.registry
bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.registry.registerDefaults();
// Typo Here: should be, registerCommandsIn
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands")


bot.login('zzzzz');
```

Your directory structure should look something like the following.  [registerCommandsIn](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandRegistry?scrollTo=registerCommandsIn) loads all commands in a given directory.

```
/commands/random.js
/index.js
```

And you should be sure to be running index.js with the [harmony flag and with no less than Node 7.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-commando#installation).

```
node index.js --harmony
```

Also, found this, on line 17 of random.js

```
message.reply("You rolled a die") + roll);
// I assume you want to send the roll
message.reply("You rolled a die" + roll);
```